# Pandas find max column, subtract from another column and replace the value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
 A    |  B     |  C  | D
14    |  5     | 10  | 5
 4    |  7     | 15  | 6
100   | 220    |  6  | 7
```

For each row in column A,B,C, I want the find the max value and from it subtract column D and replace it.

Expected result:

```
 A   |  B   |  C  |  D
 9   |  5   | 10  |  5
 4   |  7   |  9  |  6
100  | 213  |  6  |  7
```

So for the first row, it would select 14(the max out of 14,5,10), subtract column D from it (14-5 =9) and replace the result(replace initial value 14 with 9)

I  know how to find the max value of A,B,C and from it subctract D, but I am stucked on the replacing part.

I tought on putting the result in another column called E, and then find again the max of A,B,C and replace with column E, but that would make no sense since I would be attempting to assign a value to a function call. Is there any other option to do this?

```
#Exmaple df
list_columns = ['A', 'B', 'C','D']
list_data = [ [14, 5, 10,5],[4, 7, 15,6],[100, 220, 6,7]]
df= pd.DataFrame(columns=list_columns, data=list_data)

#Calculate the max and subctract 
df['e'] = df[['A', 'B']].max(axis=1) - df['D']

#To replace, maybe something like this. But this line makes no sense since it's backwards
df[['A', 'B','C']].max(axis=1) = df['D']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for replace only maximal value matched by compare all values of filtered columns with maximals:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
s =  df[cols].max(axis=1)
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].eq(s, axis=0), s - df['D'], axis=0)
print (df)
     A    B   C  D
0    9    5  10  5
1    4    7   9  6
2  100  213   6  7
```

Comment: I would had never had tought of this. Thank you. I will accept the answer asap. Hope it will also help others